# Counting the frequency of varying day-events

Tags: matlab, date, matrix

Let's say I have a few matrices where the first column is a serial date, and the second column is the information for that specific date. These matrices are organized in a way that all of the dates are at a minimum number of consecutive days. In the example below (A), this number is 3. This being said, A has runs of 3 consecutive days, 4 consecutive days, 5 consecutive days, and so forth, making the consecutive day count 3+. My total set of matrices range from 2+ to 5+.

```
A=
694094   91 
694095   92 
694096   94  
694097   86
694157   95
694158   99
694159   99
694160   97
694183  100
694184   99 
694185   96 
694505   94
694506   92
694507   89
...
```

I want to find a way to count the varying amount of consecutive days per year. That is, count the amount of 3-day events, 4-day events, and onward. So, using the above example, the output would look like:

```
B=
1900 3
1901 1
....
```

Which states that there are three 3+ consecutive day events in 1900, and according to the example, only one 3+ consecutive day event in 1901. The years come from the serial date numbers, and the documentation on that can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html). My data ranges from 1900 to 2013.

So far I've tried to use the [diff](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) function to try and split the day events by the amount of 1s in a string, find those indices, and then use histc to count the events per year but I'm realizing that this is a failed approach. I'm sure accumarray could help in this situation -- but I'm still foggy on the function after going through examples on mathworks and SO.

Comment: Where do those `1900` and `1901` come from?

Comment: I will edit this into my post after I answer you question -- the serial dates documentation can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) and the dates range from 05/01/1900 -- 09/30/2013. As I said I want to find the counts per year, so my output matrix will be the years 1900 to 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
N = 3; %// 3 for 3+ events. Change it to 2 or 5 for 2+ and 5+ events respectively

%// Year IDs
year_ID = str2num(datestr(A(:,1),'yyyy')) 

%// Binary array, where ones represent consecutive dates starting with zero 
%// as the start of a pack of consecutive dates
diffA1 = [0 ; diff(A(:,1))==1]' %//'

%// Row numbers of A that signal the start of N+ events. 
%// STRFIND here works like a "sliding-matcher" if I may call it that way. 
%// It works with a matching window that slides across diffA1 to find N+ events 
%// using a proper filter. Here a filter [0 1 1] is used for 3+ events
row_ID = strfind(diffA1,[0 ones(1,N-1)]) 

%// N+ events for each year
Nplus_event = year_ID(row_ID)

%// Desired output as a count of such N+ events against each year
B = [unique(Nplus_event) histc(Nplus_event,unique(Nplus_event))]
```

Comment: Excellent! I'm going to poke around with it and confirm with my other matrices, but so far this is looking correct.

Comment: @climatefreak You got it! That's really the essence of it. Just changed the variable names to make more sense. Also as it turns out I think we don't need to work with the second column of `A` to get `B`, but please correct me otherwise.

Comment: @BasSwinckels Sure that works too, thanks! OP can incoperate that, if he/she needs an alternate way.

Comment: Ah shoot, I somehow managed to delete my edit, but that's good to hear. And you're correct, we don't need to work with second column of A, those numbers are simply there for another purpose. If you have the time, could you briefly explain the steps leading you to creating the countevent variable?

Comment: @climatefreak Added few comments alongside the codes. Check those out!

Comment: @Divakar, thank you very much! I think I finally have a hold on this now. I ran it through and everything is consistent in my matrices, so your solution worked.

Comment: @climatefreak That is great news!